# Chrome canvas rendering issue

Tags: google-chrome, canvas, rendering

I've created a small javascript game and I tested on my local computer in all major browsers and it works fine . After that I uploaded the game on my hosting server and the game won't display in Chrome , the canvas area is grey but it works fine in firefox , anyone knows why ? Here is the link for the demo

http://djordjepetrovic.rs/igrica/

Comment: It loads in my Chrome on OSX lion.

Comment: Funny thing is that it works in the same browser but from the local server , when i host the files canvas is grey :S

Comment: Are there any errors in the debug console?

Comment: nothing , the only thing that is displayed in canvas are the score and lives (the only elements that are not the images) , why it wont render images ?

Comment: All images load for me. What OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using OS X 10.8.4

Comment: I've rolled back to an earlier version of your question, so that the link is included. Without it, the question cannot be properly understood - questions should still make sense even after they have been answered, in order to help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `catcher_game.js` file I found at least on of this:

```
draw: function(){
    basket_catcherImg = new Image();
    basket_catcherImg.src = 'images/basket.png'; 
    ctx.drawImage(basket_catcherImg, this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
// ...
```

This won't work very well. It works locally on your computer as the image is cached from disk.

Loading images is an asynchronous operation so your `drawImage` needs to wait until the image is loaded - the proper way is:

```
draw: function(){
    var me = this;
    basket_catcherImg = document.createElement('img');
    basket_catcherImg.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(basket_catcherImg, me.x, me.y, me.w, me.h);
    }
    basket_catcherImg.src = 'images/basket.png'; 
    //...
```

You need to do this with other such instances of img as well.

The reason you need `me` here is because `this` is changed to the image element when called on the onload callback. So you need to keep a reference to the original `this` context.

Also replace `new Image()` to `createElement('img')` as there is currently [an issue in Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=238071) that doesn't handle this correctly.

Nice graphics by the way!